# XAudio2.7 crashes after stopping source voice

Tags: xaudio2

I am using XAudio2.7 on Windows 7 x86 application to rendrer streaming audio samples.
The source voice is created with 8KHz, mono and 16 bits per sample wave format.
Then I run a background thread which waits on voice callback and submits new buffer. Everything works great until I stop the voice and it crashes the application with access violation exception. After creating a dump file I notices that crash happens on XAudio2 internal processing thread:

[Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTeI9.png)

I tried stopping engine thread before stopping the voice but the result is the same.

Please advise,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When do you release the memory you point to for the buffer submit? Remember you have to keep all memory pointers valid until after the voice finishes processing that buffer. The data is read from application memory in real-time by the worker thread, not copied.

Calling `Stop` on the voice doesn't mean the thread has fully stopped working as soon as it returns. If you want to ensure that all buffers for a voice have finished, use `FlushSourceBuffers` after the `Stop`.

```
(void)voice->Stop( 0 ); 
(void)voice->FlushSourceBuffers();
```

You should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/tree/master/Audio)'s implementation.

> BTW, since you are using XAudio 2.7, you should be aware of this [known issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/10/09/known-issues-xaudio-2-7/).

Comment: Hi Chuck, thanks for the response. The buffer's memory is allocated on application launch and pooled in FIFO queue, hence it never released. I do call FlushSourceBuffers after Stop. I also tried using the Discontinuity API before stop, but it didn't help either. Thanks for pointing me to the"known issue" I added it to my implementation